# Can't install ubuntu-16.04.4 on new PC

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu-16.04.4 via a USB flash-drive onto a new PC with a new SSD. It's so frustrating!

The installer kept crashing, so I looked online and somebody suggested installing Fedora 1st. So I did that-- Fedora installed fine.

Now the Ubuntu installer won't erase the disk.

Maybe I should try an older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: A new version of Ubuntu is best for a new PC because there are new hardware drivers. So you could try Ubuntu 17.10.1 or the still developing version 'Bionic' to be released in April 2018 as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. See this link (and links from it), http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ ; By the way, what is the graphics chip/card in your new computer?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you can boot from the USB stick, and the problem occurs when you try to actually install.  It's likely you either need a UEFI-specific version of the Ubuntu ISO, or you need to disable "secure boot" in your machine's BIOS settings.  This may also appear (as it does on my new desktop motherboard) as "boot Legacy first" or similar.

If the machine was shipped as UEFI, especially if Windows was installed, you may also need to delete and recreate the hard disk partitions with an "MS-DOS" type boot record.